# Spring Data Repository: "find" method with orderBy gets the wrong order

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a Spring Boot application with some JPA repositories.
I defined the following method inside one of the repository interfaces:

```
    public List<Post> findAllByOrderByPublishedOnDesc();
```

Quite obviously, I would like to retrive the list of all the `Post`s sorted by `publishOn` DESC. Strangely, I get the order wrong when two or more of the posts have a value of `publishedOn` that differs only for the minute component of the LocalDateTime class (see the comments in the code below).
**What Am I doing wrong?**

Here's the example code. The test is executed with the H2 database:

Entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class Post
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        Long id;

        @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
        String sourceUrl;

        @Column
        String title;

        @Column
        LocalDateTime publishedOn;

        @LastModifiedDate
        LocalDateTime editedOn;

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        Text text;
    }
```

Repository:

```
    public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long>
    {
        public Post findBySourceUrl(String sourceUrl);
        public List<Post> findAllByOrderByPublishedOnDesc();
    }
```

Test:

```
    public class OrderByJPATest
    {
    @Autowired
    PostRepository postRepo;

    public OrderByJPATest()
    {
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrderByDays()
    {
            // First try: older by 1 day
            Post newer = insertTestEntity("newer", LocalDateTime.of(2016, 11, 13, 0, 0));
            Post older = insertTestEntity("older", LocalDateTime.of(2016, 11, 12, 0, 0));

            List<Post> ordered = postRepo.findAllByOrderByPublishedOnDesc();

            ordered.stream().forEach((post) -> log.info("{} => {}", post.getSourceUrl(), post.getPublishedOn()));

            /*
            output:
            newer => 2016-11-13T00:00
            older => 2016-11-12T00:00
            */

            assertTrue(ordered.get(0).getPublishedOn()
                    .isAfter(ordered.get(1).getPublishedOn()));

            postRepo.deleteAll();
            postRepo.flush();

            // Second try: older by 1 minute
            newer = insertTestEntity("newerBy1Min", LocalDateTime.of(2016, 11, 13, 01, 02));
            older = insertTestEntity("olderBy1Min", LocalDateTime.of(2016, 11, 13, 01, 01));

            ordered = postRepo.findAllByOrderByPublishedOnDesc();

            ordered.stream().forEach((post) -> log.info("{} => {}", post.getSourceUrl(), post.getPublishedOn()));

            /* 
            output:
            olderBy1Min => 2016-11-13T01:01
            newerBy1Min => 2016-11-13T01:02
            */

            // this assert fails!
            assertTrue(ordered.get(0).getPublishedOn()
                    .isAfter(ordered.get(1).getPublishedOn()));
    }

    private Post insertTestEntity(String url, LocalDateTime publishDate)
    {
            Text text = new Text();
            text.setValue("Testing...");
            Post post = new Post();
            post.setPublishedOn(publishDate);
            post.setSourceUrl(url);
            post.setText(text);

            return postRepo.save(post);
    }
    }
```

POM (dependencies):

```
   <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.commonmark</groupId>
            <artifactId>commonmark</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Additional dependencies -end-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you tried mapping to java.util.Date and seeing if that changes the behavior?

Comment: @neil-stockton What version of Spring Boot are you using?  And let me know if you've overridden any of the dependency versions.

Comment: @punkrocker27ka I'm using 1.4.1.RELEASE and there are no exclusions or overrides in my POM

Comment: @JustinKSU mmm interesting: switching from LocalDateTime to Date I get the right order:  `newerBy1Min => Wed Dec 13 01:02:00 CET 3916 olderBy1Min => Wed Dec 13 01:01:00 CET 3916`

Comment: Can you share your pom file.  I'm curious if you're bringing in jackson-datatype-jsr310?

Comment: @punkrocker27ka Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA by default will map Java's `LocalDateTime` to a `BLOB` instead of a `DateTime` or `Timestamp`.

The database doesn't understand how to perform a date/time sort on a BLOB.

1. Make sure you create your schema with the appropriate data type (either using the `@Column` annotation or with a SQL script).
2. Add the `hibernate-java8` dependency to your project

After performing the above steps, the correct ordering will take place.

Comment: I have `hibernate-java8` but it still doesn't work. Maybe I miss the first point of your answer. What could be an appropriate definition for the column? Can you show an example? Thank you very much.

Comment: @EvilToad I used the TIMESTAMP data type within SQL for Java's LocalDateTime.  See this full working example: https://github.com/kanderson450/stackoverflow-q40616629

Comment: Nailed it! Now it works as expected. Thank you very super much for the effort.