# I cannot order by Instant with Hibernate and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to retrieve the 10 most recently updated entities from a table. The model has a

```
@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "updated_at")
private Instant updatedAt;
```

Thus, my approach was to have a repository method like

```
findTop10ByOrderByUpdatedAtDesc();
```

which gets translated to something like

```
select [bunch of properties and so on] order by model0_.updated_at desc limit ?
```

This query does indeed return 10 elements. However, the result is not ordered. I could not find any error message or warning either. Since the project uses hibernate, the Instant is persisted as a TimeStamp in the mySQL DB. Serializing and deserializing works properly.

Steps I have taken:

1. Check if the ordering works in principle by ordering by a different property: It does
2. Build the query manually with the builder from the EntityManager: Same problem
3. Build the query manually with an @Query annotation: Same problem

It seems that everything works correctly, except that the result is not ordered. I know that JPA does not support Instants, but Hibernate added this support. I am using Spring Boot 2.0.3, Hibernate 5.6.0.Final and a mySQL DB.

Any ideas, what could be wrong or is there just no support for sorting Instants with hibernate?

PS: As you can see, this is my first stackoverflow post. Feel free to tell me, how to improve my question.

Comment: The repository method of course is ```findTop10ByOrderByUpdatedAtDesc()```

Comment: Have you tried executing the generated query manually using for example MySQL Workbench and look at the results? Also please show the complete signature of the `findTop10ByOrderByUpdatedAtDesc` method. Which return type do you use?

Comment: I havent. However, it is a timestamp and DBeaver is able to sort it in its view. So I guess it should work properly.
The return type is List<Model>

Comment: DBeaver is of course fine, too. Just copy and paste the query from your Spring logs and replace the question marks with the actual values. Spring itself will not sort your data, it will simply take the database result row by row and add it to your collection. `List` is the right choice, because it is ordered the same as the databse results.

Comment: I tried it directly on the DB and it worked properly. Is there any chance there needs to be some additional configuration for the DB connection?

Comment: That's really strange. I've never heard of any DB configuration properties that change the sorting behavior. Btw. I just found this SO question that seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616629/spring-data-repository-find-method-with-orderby-gets-the-wrong-order . If that doesn't help, I'd suggest setting a breakpoint in your IDE a debug through the code to see where (and why) the sorting gets messed up.